# Nicer alternatives to Option.get when get is guaranteed to succeed

Tags: scala

One of the reasons why Scalaz Maybe was added was to [get rid of get](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaz/sfnDnISpjPw/4KbRrVts2ZAJ):

> Some differences from std lib Option:
>
> - No unsafe get method

I understand `get` can be unsafe, but sometimes is is safe (in a code which has verified before the `Option` is not empty). There are some situations where one can easily stay away from using `get`, but sometimes it is not so obvious to me. What would be the alternatives to `get` in the following code?

```
def point(cursor:Int) : Option[XY]

def paste(cs: Seq[Int]) = {
  if (validateSelection(cs)) {
    cs.size match {
      case 2 => // between two points
        // editablePoint returning Option for general case,
        // but here it is known to succeed as validateSelection passed
        val beDiff = point(cs.head).get.xy - point(cs.last).get.xy
        ...
    case _ =>
      ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the quasi-safe `get`, you have to refactor your `validateSection`. In your example it probably returns a `Boolean`:

```
def validateSection(cs: Seq[Int]): Boolean
```

Yet, you could return an *evidence*, that `cs` is valid:

```
/* Returns the first and last values of the sequence,
 * if the sequence's length == 2. Otherwise `Empty`.
 */
def validateSection(cs: Seq[Int]): Maybe[(Int, Int)]
```

Then you could refactor your snippet as:

```
def paste(cs: Seq[Int]) = {
  match validateSelection(cs) {
    case (first, last) => 
      val beDiff = first - last
        ...
    case _ =>
      ...
  }
  ...
}
```

---

*EDIT* You can take the idea further: Create auxillary types to get away of function's partiality.

The `point` returns `Option[XY]`, i.e. it's partial. We should try to make input parameters more precise, so `point` can be total, i.e. return `XY`. Without knowing precise specification I can only sketch the solution:

```
case class Selection(/* ... */)

/* Constructed from `Selection` */
case class Cursor()

object Selection {
  def first: Cursor = ???
  def last: Cursor = ???
}

/* If `cs` is valid, we return a `ValidSelection`, othersise `Empty`. */
def validateSelection(cs: Seq[Int]): Maybe[Selection]

/* With more precise type, we can have total `point`. */
def point(cursor: Cursor): XY
```

This approach may look boilerplaty at first, but here we use the advantage of having the type system. Avoid [stringly typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) or *List-typed* programming.

Comment: `validateSection` validates selection which may be of any length, and tells me any `point` calls will succeed. I understand the spirit of what you write - though. It would be not validating at all and leaving the validation to the `point` call itself, and then handle failure properly. The calls can be extracted to one initial place and handed in one condition, to avoid condition spaghetti.

Comment: @Suma, I amended the answer with further refactored approach.